# Find the kernel and image of a transform

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $T : M_{2 \times 2} (F) \to M_{2 \times 2} (F)$ such that $T(A) = \begin{bmatrix}2 & -1\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix} A-A\begin{bmatrix}-3& 1\\-4 & 1\end{bmatrix} $

Find $Ker(T)$ and $Im(T)$ ?!

I did try to solve it by considering that $ \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ is a base, but couldn't proceed further!!

Comment: Apply $\;T\;$ to that base and see what happens!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

$$T\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2&\!-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-3&1\\-4&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}5&\!-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Now write the rightmost matrix as a linear combination of the basis you chose, and the coefficients there give you the first **column** of the matrix representing $\;T\;$ (Pay attention! This is waaaay easier than it may look at first sight...)

Once you have the matrix representing $\;T\;$, you can find its kernel, which will be $\;T\,'$s, and its *columns space*, which will give you Im$\,T\;$